# URL Not Found - Adding a Custom Domain - GCP App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to add a custom domain in GCP's App Engine section. But when I click on the "Add a Custom Domain" button, it goes to URL not found page: https://console.cloud.google.com/,appengine,settings,domains,add

I've followed the instructions as per here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains

Any idea what could be causing this?

I've tried contacting support, but they were useless. Its weird, because it was working last week for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. Then I chose another project, opened the option to add a new domain, got the link, and changed the project id. Try this: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains/add?serviceId=default&project=PUT_YOUT_PROJECT_ID

Replace PUT_YOUT_PROJECT_ID with your project id.